# Find the smallest number of positive integer divisors of $a+b$ knowing that $k=\frac{ab+c^2}{a+b}$

Tags: factoring

Consider the positive integers $a, b, c$ such that the fraction

$k=\frac{ab+c^2}{a+b}$ 

Is a positive integer less than $a$ and $b$. Find the smallest number of positive integer divisors of $a+b$

Comment: Please write an *informative* title.  This one is basically useless.

Comment: What have you tried?  Is there any reason $a+b$ cannot be prime?  $b$ can't be $1$ because $k$ can't be less.  $a=4,b=1,c=2$ works aside from that.

Comment: Well I have tried to prove that a + b is prime but I think if a + b is prime then a + b must be odd so a will be even and b will be odd. <-- That's what I have tried

Comment: I don't think you can prove that $a+b$ must be prime, but I suspect it can be.  You just need one example where it is and you are done.

Comment: No, in your example $k=\frac {20+4}{5+4}$ which is not an integer.  It looks really hard to get $k \lt a,b$ be an integer.  Do they mean strictly less than?

Comment: $a=3, b=5, c=1$ -> $k=2$ but $a+b=8$ <-- which is not prime

Comment: where did you get the problem?

Comment: Well from my teacher and my teacher get this problem from the olympiad of Russia

Comment: unless $a+b$ can be prime the winner is   $a: 10, \; \;  b: 15, \; \;  c: 5, \; \;  k: 7, \; \;  a+b =25 =  5^2$  with three divisors.

Comment: $a:3, b:5, c:1 -> k:2, a+b=8$ which have 4 divisors

Comment: Wait I know the idea well you need to prove that a + b will be never prime and the smallest divisors is 3 which is a square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, there's a solution with 3 divisors and it suffices to prove that $a+b$ cannot be prime.
Suppose that $a+b=p$ is prime.
We have the condition $c<a,b$ (equivalent to the given constraints).
We also have $p|c^2-a^2$, which implies that $p|(c-a)(c+a)$. This is now a contradiction as $|c-a|$ and $(c+a)$ are both less than $p$.